# How to remove list view from media library?

Tags: admin, uploads

I'd like to remove list mode from media library and let users see grid-mode only.
I've seen it's a matter of

```
$modes = array( 'grid', 'list' );
```

in `upload.php`

but I don't want to mod the core.

Answer (score 11):

This is a little hacky, but doesn't require you to edit core files, which you should never do, as you are aware.

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    $_GET['mode'] = 'grid';
}, 100);
```

This will always force the mode into grid view.

What it does not do,

- it does not remove the List View icon
- it does not change the query argument in the URL

To remove the List View icon you can do something to the effect of:

```
add_action('admin_head', function() {

    ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        .view-switch .view-list {
            display: none;
        }
    <style>

    <?php

});
```

Alternatively, to remove the `?mode=list` query argument from the URL, you could:

- use JavaScript to modify the `search` property found on `windlow.location`
- redirect the user server side using `wp_redirect()` by inspecting `$_GET` super global for the `mode` query variable array key **(recommended)**.

For example you could rewrite the first snippet to:

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {

    if ( isset( $_GET['mode'] ) && $_GET['mode'] !== 'grid' ) {
        wp_redirect(admin_url('upload.php?mode=grid'));
        exit;
    } else {
        //required by upload.php, handle the case if user just navigates to... 
        //http://www.example.com/wp-admin/upload.php (with no mode query argument)
        $_GET['mode'] = 'grid';
    }

}, 100);
```

Or alternativey without the need for an else block,

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {

    if ( strpos(admin_url('upload.php'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== false 
         || (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] === 'list') ) {
        wp_redirect(admin_url('upload.php?mode=grid'));
        exit;
    } 

}, 100);
```

...the above snippet ensures that no matter what, either of the following URLs,

- http://www.example.com/wp-admin/upload.php
- http://www.example.com/wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list

...will always be redirected to,

- http://www.example.com/wp-admin/upload.php?mode=grid

Combined with hiding the List View icon via injecting CSS on the `admin_head` hook, produces the desired result you are after.

Comment: Thank you :) I was just wandering aroud a similar solution :)

Comment: @Simone.p No problem, I've tested the above and it produces the desired effect you are after.

Comment: Excellent to the point answer!